# Can I have application versions in python27 and python37 in Google App Engine Standard (both types)

Tags: google-app-engine, python-3.7

I want to test Python 3.7 on Google App Engine Standard.

I am afraid if I upload application with python37 old application will stop working and will be no revert to previous python27.

Can you share some experience if it possible to keep both runtime versions?

It is not clear for me.

[image]

I read [Python 3.7 on Google App Engine - documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/release-notes) but not found information.

Answer (score 5):

You have 3 main options, ranked from easier to 'harder' to do:

1. Just deploy this test you want to do in a new project, and you don't have to worry about your old application getting replaced.
2. Deploy this test to a [new service](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#runtime_and_app_elements). Just add the line `service: whatevername` to the `app.yaml` file of your test, and deploy it as usual with `$gcloud app deploy`. Voilà, you have a new service.
3. You can deploy this test in your default service, but to avoid stopping the previous one, add the `--no-stop-previous-version` flag to your `$ gcloud app deploy` command. After that, you can [split traffic](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/splitting-traffic#splitting_traffic_across_multiple_versions) between this test and your actual app.

To be honest, I would go with options 1 or 2, as they are far more simple to deploy, and you can later on [delete the test project](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#shutting_down_projects) or [delete the new service](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/services/delete) if you wish to.

Comment: I will think which version is safe and fast thank you for new ways suggestions.

Comment: @Chameleon No problem! Just bear in mind that Python 3.7 in Standard is in beta right now, and there are [differences](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/python-differences), as there were differences between Python 2 & Python 3.

Comment: That is big problem but I want reuse same application.